# Updating Fluent nHibernate causes problems with missing property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, c#-3.0, updating

I am trying to update the nHibernate version in my application.
I used nuGet and updated NHibernate v2.1.2.4000 to v3.3.2.4000
And fluent NHibernate from v1.1.0.685 to v1.3.0.733

I was expecting a few issues but the error I'm getting is odd and I can't quite figure it out.

In my "many to many" convention there is this line:

```
var userDefined = instance.Relationship.Columns.UserDefined.FirstOrDefault();
if (userDefined != null)
{
  instance.Relationship.Column(userDefined.EntityType.Name + "Id");
}
```

The problem is that after the update of the DLLs the "UserDefined" property no longer exists. What I can't understand is whether I need to redefine it somewhere, or whether there's a different way of accessing that property.

I was under the impression that the "UserDefined" property was part of fluent nHibernate.
Does anyone know how to get this one working?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

FluentNHibernate refactored the way it represents specified values.

Before there was one value and indicators who set them (default, convention, explicit). Now there are values for all three kinds and when reading it uses something like `explicit ?? convention ?? default` hence the tests for explicit/user defined values are no longer needed.

Remove all lines but `instance.Relationship.Column(userDefined.EntityType.Name + "Id");`

Comment: userDefined doesn't exist without the first line which is this:

var userDefined = instance.Relationship.Columns.UserDefined.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: There is a: instance.ChildType.FullName

But what drives me nuts is that I can find no documentation what happened to "Relationship.Columns.UserDefined" in NHibernate 3

Comment: it is part of FluentNHibernate which is almost dead since NHibernate introduced Mapping By Code. He managed to integrate his Refactoring but documentation and bugfixes are starving since then. See NH 2.1 in https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started